# What does David Hume mean by the word "dull" in this quote?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, archaicisms

In his essay ["The Skeptic,"](http://www.econlib.org/library/LFBooks/Hume/hmMPL18.html) 18th-century English philosopher David Hume concludes:

> In a word, human life is more governed by fortune than by reason; is to be regarded more as a **dull** pastime than as a serious occupation; and is more influenced by particular humour, than by general principles. Shall we engage ourselves in it with passion and anxiety? It is not worthy of so much concern. Shall we be indifferent about what happens? We lose all the pleasure of the game by our phlegm° and carelessness. While we are reasoning concerning life, life is gone; and death, though perhaps they receive him differently, yet treats alike the fool and the philosopher. To reduce life to exact rule and method, is commonly a painful, oft a fruitless occupation: And is it not also a proof, that we overvalue the prize for which we contend? Even to reason so carefully concerning it, and to fix with accuracy its just idea, would be overvaluing it, were it not that, to some tempers, this occupation is one of the most amusing, in which life could possibly be employed.

My question is about the use of the word "dull" in the first sentence (which I've boldfaced for easy reference). In context, it seems he doesn't mean "boring" as is the modern meaning of the word, as that contradicts the thrust of the paragraph. What was the historical meaning of the word that he is using here?

Comment: I believe he means a pastime engaged in a blasé, disinterested manner, lacking curiosity, structure or purpose. This in contrast with what he can expect his reader to attribute to engagement in "a serious occupation."

Comment: Did you look up the definition of "dull"??

Comment: (And why can't he mean "boring"?)

Comment: @bitless - that reading would mean he's directly contradicting himself, as he says we shouldn't be indifferent a few sentences later.

Comment: @HotLicks - yes, though I don't have access to the OED which would be useful for historical meaning; and if he means "boring" then he is contradicting himself within the same paragraph, which is why I suspect he means something else.

Comment: Look up synonyms for "dull".  "Tedious" is one, and it seems to fit quite well into his tirade.

Comment: Where does he say "we shouldn't be indifferent"?

Comment: @Ghopper21 He appears to be rhetorically weighing concerns about approaching life too dogmatically one way or another, illustrating anxiety v stolidity. 
Then he seems to conclude it's useless to worry much about "how" one lives altogether, ending on a winking self-referential note that clearly there are those who like doing just that – as its own reward and not a means to an end.

Comment: @HotLicks - I don't think "tedious" fits the context of the paragraph at all. He's not saying life should be a tedious boring pastime. To the contrary, he's saying we should take (an appropriate amount of) pleasure in the game of life.

Comment: @Margana - "Shall we be indifferent about what happens? We lose all the pleasure of the game by our phlegm° and carelessness."

Comment: Hume is being world-weary to show us how sophisticated he is. It's a common game among the intellectual set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we can tease out the meaning by examining the three contrasts of the first sentence:

> **fortune**<sup>1</sup> (i.e., chance) vs **reason**
>   **dull**<sup>2</sup> vs **serious**<sup>3</sup> (i.e., involving earnest thought)
>   particular **humour** (i.e, emotion) vs general **principles**

So, on the right-hand sides we have rationality, its methods, and its results.  On the left-hand side, we have things that undermine rationality.  I think this forces us to take the older meaning (per the *OED*) of "dull" as stupid or foolish (as opposed to boring).  This gives us the nice contrasts to rationality of its enemies -- chance, foolishness, and emotionality.

From the *OED*:
1. Fortune. "1. Chance, hap, or luck"
2. Dull. "1. ...obtuse, stupid, inapprehensive.  In early use sometimes: Wanting wit, fatuous, foolish."
3. Serious. "Having, involving, expressing, arising from earnest purpose or thought."

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. Any chance you are able to quote the OED on this?

Comment: Sure.  Are you interested in "fortune" and "serious" or just "dull"?

Comment: Mostly "dull" but if there are bits in "fortune" and "serious" that illuminate the contrast, that'd be appreciated also. (Wish the OED were available online!)

Comment: @Ghopper21Done. See the edited answer.  The *OED* is online.  You just have to pay for access.  Some libraries have subscriptons.